# How to convert a string value to hexadecimal without changing the value in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a variable which has a hexadecimal string value. And I want Perl to read it as a hexadecimal value so that I can do some additions to it. But I don't want the value to be changed.

For example:

```
$string = 'AB320000';
```

I want,

```
$hex = $string = 'AB320000';
```

so that I can do:

```
 $hex + 0x10 + 0x20;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't understand how math and computers work. You have decimal, and hexadecimal and binary -- and other formats. Those are mere notations, ways to express numbers. Computers tend to only work with the one that they have the rudimentary components to manipulate. The computer you're on probably requires binary. So here is how things are going to work.

1. You're going to give your magic box a "string".
2. You're going to tell your magic box this string is a number in hexadecimal format.
3. Your computer is going to convert that string to a number implementation that it can manipulate: like an int, or a float -- but it'll be stored in binary.
4. You're going to instruct your magic box to do something -- like compute the addition on that int or float.
5. You're going to demand that the resulting number be arbitrarily rendered in hexadecimal format.

That's how it has to work. So the questions are,

1. *How do I get a hexadecimal string to a number (in Perl)?*

   - If you're using literals in code, exactly the way you did in the question `0xFF` etc.
2. *How do I add integers (or floats or whatever, and in Perl)?*

   - Hint: it's simply the `+` operator, as used in your question.
3. *How do I render an integer as a hexadecimal string (in Perl)?*

   - Hint: `printf( '%x', 255 )`

And, all of those questions are probably already answered on SO.